# Bypass framework7.js redirection on some links

Tags: javascript, html, html-framework-7

I am using a mobile template on my websie bought on a known website and this template is using framework7.

I did my full website for mobile version without problem but now I have one : I want to integrate a facebook login button, the code on php side is already done (works fine on pc version), but when I call this link I have the issue (visible in the chrome console) :

```
GET https://www.xxxx.com/auth/fb/login 404 (Not Found) framework7.min.js
```

How to bypass the framework7 for some urls, like this one ? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just add class "external" to the links
for example:

`<a href="somepage.html" class="external">link</a>`

you can read more about it here: http://www.idangero.us/framework7/docs/linking-pages.html#.VX_1wM_BzGc